# How does one generate c# code from an in memory object

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

What I'm basically trying to achieve is the same as what a winforms designer file does. Create the type with properties values that are set.
So for arguments sake. I have an IN MEMORY object:
Pseudo code:

```
type Person inherits Component 
  name = 'Peter'  
  title = 'Mr'
```

Then the code that would be generated is similar to what would be if it were placed on a windows form and the code generated in the form.designer.cs

Now. I realize that one can use the CodeDom classes. But this involves manually building up the type. What I need is a class or function that can use any existing object including its properties that are set and generate the c# source code for the type. So basically something similar to

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = 'Peter';

string output = SomeType.ReadObjectAndReturnSourceCode(peter);
```

So in short : does such functionality exist somewhere in the .net  framework?

Comment: How about just serialising the object - which writes all of the properties.  Then deserialising it when you need it?

Comment: No inbuilt way, but its really not that hard as long as you don't have to get too fancy. If all you need is a simple class with property and method stubs, building the code is rather trivial.

Comment: But it is unclear what you are asking. Do you only need public property and method stubs? Or do you actually want their implementation along with any existing private/protected members, inheritance, interface implementation, etc? Because that is an altogether different ballgame. You would basically be asking for a .NET decompiler.

Comment: Try playing around with Roslyn. There's a lot you can do there, and it definitely can solve your problem with enough effort. But I don't think there's any two - minute way. You'll have to use reflection on your in memory object to create properties in the class you're building using roslyn